# CSS: How to allow the hover state only on devices which support hover?

Tags: css, hover, touch

I was looking for a way to prevent touch devices from "simulating" the hover event. The reason is that you can't hover on touch devices like you can on a desktop with the cursor and this sometimes interfere with the user experience.

Because I didn't found any solutions online I thought I post my own solution here. I hope this will help someone :)

Comment: FYI css-tricks has a good article about `@media cursor` and `@media hover` https://css-tricks.com/touch-devices-not-judged-size/ may be interesting for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achieved to only hover on devices which have a real hover state with two media queries.

- The first media query makes sure that the CSS is only executed when the current device has a real hover state. This works in nearly every browser: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-interaction
- The second media query is to support IE11 because the first one isn't supported by IE11  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-ms-high-contrast

```css
@media (hover: hover), (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
  div:hover {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me!</div>
```

Comment: The best answer I see so far. support all platform, simple and clean. More people should see this solution.

Comment: I am using FF 79.0 on Windows 10 and when I run the code snippet the div does not turn red. Works in all other browsers except FF. Thoughts?

Comment: @Mark works fine for me in FF (latest and also 79.0). Can you still reproduce it?

Comment: @Jan - After reading everywhere that it should be working, I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling FF and it has been successfully working ever since then. I was not experiencing any other oddities in FF. No clue.

Comment: This doesn’t work on Samsung Android phones. They incorrectly report they support hover. https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/css-media-hover-samsung.html